# Azure Pipeline failing to build Azure Function App

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

I created an **Azure Function** in **Visual Studio 2019** and used **Azure Pipelines** to build a Continuous Integration.

Project Settings:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="4.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.8" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

[image]

Azure DevOps Pipeline in Visual Studio 2019:

[image]

Azure DevOps Pipeline on the Azure DevOps site:

[image]

The project is not building and gives the following error:

```
The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.515\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(137,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.1. Either target .NET Core 2.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 3.1. [D:\a\1\s\MyProject\MyProject.csproj])
```

[image]

What should I do fix the issue?

Comment: Are you building on a microsoft hosted agent or are you running your own?

Comment: I think it is Microsoft Hosted Agent in Azure DevOps. I did not have to manually setup anything, all done via Visual Studio 2019 Azure Pipelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the **Agent Specification** from **vs2017-win2016** to **windows-2019** which installs .NET Core 3.1 that Alex AIT provided as an answer. Now the build and deployment is successful.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The build agent is trying to run the build with an older SDK, possibly .net core 3.0 or 2.x.

If multiple SDK are installed, the latest is usually selected, but you can force a certain SDK version by putting a [`global.json`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjB75KxibPqAhUBC-wKHeDeC3YQFjAAegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdotnet%2Fcore%2Ftools%2Fglobal-json&usg=AOvVaw1Ac5MPByUUbZX--3_F-Aqx) next to the source code.

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "3.1.101",
    "rollForward": "latestFeature"
  }
}
```

This can be combined with the `Use .NET Core` task, which ensures that the desired version of the SDK is installed. The task can also be used without a global JSON by specifying the desired version.

[image: use .NET Core task]

If you host your own agent, it might also be an option to simply log into the server and install the SDK manually.

Finally, sometimes it is easier to use the *dotnet core* task instead of the *Visual Studio Build*. Though it is my opinion that both should work.

[image: dotnet core task]

Comment: I don't see a **.NET Core** task in the pipeline steps. This Pipeline was auto selected when I choose Azure Pipeline from the latest version of **Visual Studio 2019 Preview**. There is **Use NuGet 5.0** as shown in the original post. Should I modify the Pipeline to add **.NET Core**?

Comment: Yeah, I suggest add use both tasks I mentioned